# LoRa Class B implementation TDMA by Arduino and SX1278

Tags: arduino, lora, lorawan

I'm building a Lora network, with two SX1278 modules and Arduino Uno.
Lora is based on three classes. A , B and C,
The question is :
for implementing Class B, **Does it need to change Lora module registers?!
or differences between classes are just between the time they communicate to each other?**
and If you have a source code, it really makes life easier.

Comment: Tip: type in google `something github` , like `Arduino Uno Lora github` and you'll have the source code. What research did you do? Did you at least try searching like at least `lora classes` in google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or implementing Class B, Does it need to change Lora module registers?

Well, yes. It needs to do a RX window from time to time.

> or differences between classes are just between the time they communicate to each other?

Generally yes. Almost all implementation of power-saving methods in wireless communication may be reduced to difference in "just the time between they communicate" - this is an oversimplification. But generally, yes, classes manipulate the times when downlink are possible from gateway to beacon.

Class A can send message anytime and it receives messages only right after sending. Class B is class A with periodic synchronized receiving windows. And Class C can receive messages anytime - keeps RX always open.

From [lora-allience.org/about-lorawan](https://lora-alliance.org/about-lorawan/):

> Class A – Lowest power, bi-directional end-devices:
>
> The default class which must be supported by all LoRaWAN end-devices,
> class A communication is always initiated by the end-device and is
> fully asynchronous. Each uplink transmission can be sent at any time
> and is followed by two short downlink windows, giving the opportunity
> for bi-directional communication, or network control commands if
> needed. This is an ALOHA type of protocol. The end-device is able to
> enter low-power sleep mode for as long as defined by its own
> application: there is no network requirement for periodic wake-ups.
> This makes class A the lowest power operating mode, while still
> allowing uplink communication at any time. Because downlink
> communication must always follow an uplink transmission with a
> schedule defined by the end-device application, downlink communication
> must be buffered at the network server until the next uplink event.
>
> Class B – Bi-directional end-devices with deterministic downlink
> latency:
>
> In addition to the class A initiated receive windows, class B devices
> are synchronised to the network using periodic beacons, and open
> downlink ‘ping slots’ at scheduled times. This provides the network
> the ability to send downlink communications with a deterministic
> latency, but at the expense of some additional power consumption in
> the end-device. The latency is programmable up to 128 seconds to suit
> different applications, and the additional power consumption is low
> enough to still be valid for battery powered applications.
>
> Class C – Lowest latency, bi-directional end-devices:
>
> In addition to the class A structure of uplink followed by two
> downlink windows, class C further reduces latency on the downlink by
> keeping the receiver of the end-device open at all times that the
> device is not transmitting (half duplex). Based on this, the network
> server can initiate a downlink transmission at any time on the
> assumption that the end-device receiver is open, so no latency. The
> compromise is the power drain of the receiver (up to ~50mW) and so
> class C is suitable for applications where continuous power is
> available. For battery powered devices, temporary mode switching
> between classes A & C is possible, and is useful for intermittent
> tasks such as firmware over-the-air updates.

Comment: is there any way I can message you PV for more details about LoRA ?

Comment: Well, you can write just here xd :p

Comment: OK:)),  how can I implement LoRa classes? I mean, Is a pair of SX1278 enough for start or it needs sx13xx modules?!  Second, For changing class for example change A to B, does it need to send special command bits by gateway? or Should i change register bits?

Comment: should I change communication class by just changing a command bite ? or should I write all of the protocol by myself?, and Third, for class B, Is beacon format, fixed for all Lora standard networks?! I mean, Does it have a universal format or Is it open and flexible for each network?
forth, What is LoraWan stack!? Is this a device?  <<<thanks in advanced <3>>

Comment: `how can I implement LoRa classes?` that's very broad - if you wish to implement the whole stack, you should most probably start a company and hire more programmers. Pragmatic answer is you don't, use existing implementations, like LoRaMAC-node. Or mbed. Or other. `is a pair of SX1278 enough for start` yes  `t needs sx13xx modules?` don't know what that is `does it need to send special command bits by gateway?` yes, gateway has to know when to send data, config and time synchronization is crucial. `Should i change register bits?` no idea - I didn't read SX1278 specs.

Comment: `should I.. should I...` what you should or shouldn't do are hard design questions. What you should do depends on what you _want_ to do. Do what you want. `Is beacon format, fixed for all Lora standard networks?` No idea, I doubt that, but maybe, I do not believe anyone cares about LoRa 0.9 standard. Use the newest standard anyway - it's 1.0.4 now. `Does it have a universal format or` Define "universal format". `Is it open` LoRaWAN standard is publicly available, i'ts open in that sense.

Comment: `flexible for each network?` Define "flexible". I do not understand "for each network", there is one network here, it's LoRa network `What is LoraWan stack?` I would understand it as a collection of libraries, software and hardware, that is able to handle all layers of communication through LoRaWAN network. Read about OSI model. `Is this a device?` No.